# How to connect to ESP32-wroom-32

Tags: usb, tty, 23.04, serial-port, putty

I'm starting – or *trying* to start – working with an ESP32-WROOM-32 board, using Ubuntu 23.04, ultimately in order to install [WLED](https://kno.wled.ge/) to control lighting via [Home-Assistant](https://www.home-assistant.io/).

So far, I've connected the ESP32 boards via USB to the computer, the cable is a data cable; or it seems to be, as the same cable allows my phones (a Pixel 8 and a Pixel 6A) to function as webcams for the computer.

Using `lsusb` gives:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 2109:0812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 8087:0025 Intel Corp. Wireless-AC 9260 Bluetooth Adapter
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 1462:7b85 Micro Star International PRO CARBON   
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 328f:006d EMEET HD Webcam eMeet C960
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 2109:2812 VIA Labs, Inc. VL812 Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 041e:3273 Creative Technology, Ltd Stage V2
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1b1c:1b3c Corsair Corsair Gaming HARPOON RGB Mouse
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c336 Logitech, Inc. G213 Prodigy Gaming Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

And `ls /dev/tty*` gives:

```
/dev/tty    /dev/tty23  /dev/tty39  /dev/tty54      /dev/ttyS10  /dev/ttyS26
/dev/tty0   /dev/tty24  /dev/tty4   /dev/tty55      /dev/ttyS11  /dev/ttyS27
/dev/tty1   /dev/tty25  /dev/tty40  /dev/tty56      /dev/ttyS12  /dev/ttyS28
/dev/tty10  /dev/tty26  /dev/tty41  /dev/tty57      /dev/ttyS13  /dev/ttyS29
/dev/tty11  /dev/tty27  /dev/tty42  /dev/tty58      /dev/ttyS14  /dev/ttyS3
/dev/tty12  /dev/tty28  /dev/tty43  /dev/tty59      /dev/ttyS15  /dev/ttyS30
/dev/tty13  /dev/tty29  /dev/tty44  /dev/tty6       /dev/ttyS16  /dev/ttyS31
/dev/tty14  /dev/tty3   /dev/tty45  /dev/tty60      /dev/ttyS17  /dev/ttyS4
/dev/tty15  /dev/tty30  /dev/tty46  /dev/tty61      /dev/ttyS18  /dev/ttyS5
/dev/tty16  /dev/tty31  /dev/tty47  /dev/tty62      /dev/ttyS19  /dev/ttyS6
/dev/tty17  /dev/tty32  /dev/tty48  /dev/tty63      /dev/ttyS2   /dev/ttyS7
/dev/tty18  /dev/tty33  /dev/tty49  /dev/tty7       /dev/ttyS20  /dev/ttyS8
/dev/tty19  /dev/tty34  /dev/tty5   /dev/tty8       /dev/ttyS21  /dev/ttyS9
/dev/tty2   /dev/tty35  /dev/tty50  /dev/tty9       /dev/ttyS22
/dev/tty20  /dev/tty36  /dev/tty51  /dev/ttyprintk  /dev/ttyS23
/dev/tty21  /dev/tty37  /dev/tty52  /dev/ttyS0      /dev/ttyS24
/dev/tty22  /dev/tty38  /dev/tty53  /dev/ttyS1      /dev/ttyS25
```

Now, the `/dev/tty*` output doesn't change regardless of the ESP32 board being plugged in, or not, whereas unplugging the board results in the `Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1a86:7523 QinHeng Electronics CH340 serial converter` entry being removed from `lsusb`, so I assume that that's the entry relating to the board?

Searching online brings up a couple of articles:

- [USB-to-UART Bridge on Development Board](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html#establish-serial-connection-with-esp32) article, which suggests I may need a USB-to-UART cable, and
- [Standard Toolchain Setup for Linux and macOS](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/linux-macos-setup.html#standard-toolchain-setup-for-linux-and-macos).

(Both links go to pages on [Espressif.com](//espressif.com/)

I've followed the guide outlined in the second article listed above, and...nothing seems to have changed/improved. To be sure I've logged-out and logged-in to the system without a power-cycle, and then I've power-cycled the system off and back on (it's a cliche for a reason, right).

After seeing [steeldriver's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497310/how-to-connect-to-esp32-wroom-32?noredirect=1#comment2622777_1497310) (below):

> his may be the result of a ID conflict with the brltty device driver - see for example [Unable to use USB dongle based on USB-serial converter chip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670636/unable-to-use-usb-dongle-based-on-usb-serial-converter-chip)

I followed the link, and followed the advice offered by Fehlrersturm in [their answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1497310/how-to-connect-to-esp32-wroom-32?noredirect=1#comment2622777_1497310), and commented out the `ENV{PRODUCT}...` line (as below).

```
# Device: 1A86:7523
# Baum [NLS eReader Zoomax (20 cells)]
# ENV{PRODUCT}=="1a86/7523/*", ENV{BRLTTY_BRAILLE_DRIVER}="bm", GOTO="brltty_usb_run"
```

This led to an additional entry – /dev/ttyUSB0 – when I ran `ls /dev/tty*`. This is where I'm stuck again, the guide "[Establish Serial Connection to ESP32 - Windows and Linux](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/get-started/establish-serial-connection.html#windows-and-linux)" says to use PuTTY, which I tried (using the settings shown in the image, which was shown on their site):

[image: Image showing PuTTY window, showing the relevant settings that I copied]

When I hit the "Open" button, nothing happens. The button returns to its normal state, there are no new windows opened, so far as I can tell there is no result at all.

Following another [comment from steeldriver](make sure to add your user to the dialout group ...), below:

> make sure to add your user to the dialout group ...

This was done, and to be sure the group was updated/refreshed, I logged out and then back in, and later power-cycled the system.

To be sure that I was added to the `dialout` group, I used `getent group | grep dialout`, which gave the result:

```
dialout:x:20:david
```

I then followed a few other paths, which included the advice to run `sudo dmesg | grep ttyUSB0` (the advice didn't specifically suggest using `sudo`, but without `sudo` I get an error message stating that "Operation not permitted"), which gave the response:

```
[  308.540203] usb 1-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

I don't know if this is useful, though it feels like it should be?

So, my question is pretty much: what am I missing? How do I connect to this board?

Obviously – despite using Ubuntu for more than ten years at this point – I'm not particularly familiar with inner-workings, so an [ELI5](https://www.dictionary.com/e/slang/eli5/) (or lower) explanation would be very much appreciated, if that's at all possible.

Comment: This *may* be the result of a ID conflict with the brltty device driver - see for example [Unable to use USB dongle based on USB-serial converter chip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670636/unable-to-use-usb-dongle-based-on-usb-serial-converter-chip)

Comment: make sure to add your user to the dialout group ... if putty still doesn't work try a different serial terminal (GNU screen, minicom etc.)

Comment: Hey, steeldriver; I used `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER` to attempt to do that before attempting to connect with PuTTY. Though I didn't think to check that my user was actually added to the group. I'll do that in a few minutes, and thanks for your continued efforts.

Comment: Yeah you will need to start a new session (e.g. log out and back in) to make sure the updated group membership is applied

Comment: I should've clarified, but yeah: I did log-out and back in, and also power-cycled the system a little later as well to be sure. Using `getent group | grep dialout` in the terminal I can see my user identified, the output being: `dialout:x:20:david`, if that helps to identify or narrow down the problems?

Comment: I've edited the question a little to add a couple more details, in addition to my previous comment there's also the output of `udo dmesg | grep ttyUSB0`, which gives: `[  308.540203] usb 1-3: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0`.